# How to remove all Gitlab repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

I have created several repositories in GitLab.Now I want to delete or remove all repository at once. How can I do this? is there any API available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you [list all projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-all-projects), get a list of IDs and loop over the list: for every project id you [remove the project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#remove-project).

You can use a [GitLab client](https://about.gitlab.com/applications/#cli-clients) (an [API wrapper](https://about.gitlab.com/applications/#api-clients)), they exist for almost any language.

Comment: It will fetch only 20 repo at a time. is there any API to get all at once?

Comment: I don't think so. Some organizations have a lot of repos and Gitlab doesn't want to be overloaded with requests.

Comment: are you aware there ia a difference between a gitlab project and the repository within the project?

Answer (score 2):

I used the Gitlab's API to list and remove a bulk of projects I migrated by mistake, I made an small python script for it.

> DISCLAIMER: **BE VERY CAREFUL USING THE FOLLOWING CODE**. Read the code thoroughly. you alone are solely and personally responsible for your results.

That being said, here it is:

```py
import requests
import json

def get_project_ids():

    url = "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/users/{yourUserId}/projects"

    querystring = {"owned":"true","simple":"true","per_page":"50"}

    payload = ""
    headers = {'authorization': 'Bearer {yourToken}'}

    response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    projects = json.loads(response.text)
    projects_ids = list(map(lambda project: project.get('id'), projects))

    return projects_ids


def remove_project(project_id):
    url_temp = "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/{project}"
    headers = {'authorization': 'Bearer {yourToken}'}
    querystring = ""
    payload = ""

    url = url_temp.format(project=project_id)

    response = requests.request("DELETE", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    project = json.loads(response.text)
    print(project)


def main():
    projects_ids = get_project_ids()

    url_temp = "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/{project}"
    headers = {'authorization': 'Bearer {yourToken}'}
    querystring = ""
    payload = ""

    for project_id in projects_ids:

        url = url_temp.format(project=project_id)

        response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        project = json.loads(response.text)
        print(str(project.get('id')) + " " + project.get('name'))
        print("Removing")
        # remove_project(project_id)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Replace `{yourUserId}` and `{yourToken}` with the corresponding [info](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#authentication). Uncomment the `remove_project()` function to remove projects, again I will not be held responsible or liable in any way for the code presented above.

Comment: Zap. Take that hundreds of gitlab projects.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create a personal access token:

> Go to `profile`/`preferences`/`access tokens` or just [click here](https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens)
> [image]

Repalce your token in `token` variable in this code bellow:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

// Your authorization token here
const token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

// fetch all projects
axios
  .get("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?visibility=private", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
  .then(async function (response) {
    // get all projects IDs
    let ids = response.data.map((e) => e.id);
    // delete all
    for (let el of ids) {
      await axios.delete(`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${el}/`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  });
```

You can change the visibility `?visibility=private` or `?visibility=public`

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to the project page
2. Select "Settings"
3. If you have enough rights at the bottom of the page then will be a button for
   "Dangerous settings" (i.e. project settings that may result in data loss) or
   "Remove project" (in newer GitLab versions)
4. Push this button and follow the instructions

Comment: I want to delete all not single repo.

Comment: are you aware there ia a difference between a gitlab project and the repository within the project?